# calling an activity from a fragment class with an onclick method

Tags: android, eclipse

i am developing an android application, and i made use of the fragment class.. i know how to implement an onclick listener in an Activity class but am finding it really difficult to do same for the fragment class.

here is my fragment class code

```
package info.eoilimited.tabPager.thespot;

import com.eoilimited.thespot.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Resturants extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_resturant, container, false);

        ImageView comment = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        comment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //I know I need to add the code here, but I don't know
                //the right syntax         
                startActivity(new Intent());
            } 
        }); 
        return rootView;
    }
}`
```

Comment: @Override
                      public void onClick(View v)
                      {
                      
                       startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(Resturants.this),SignUpActivity.class));
                      } 
            });

Comment: that is my code and i still get an error

Answer (score 1):

You need to do as follows:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class));
```

First param the context (the `FragmentActivity`): inside a `Fragment` you can use `getActivity()`.
Second param the new activity (like a `Intent` inside an normal `Activity`).

Comment: @Override
                      public void onClick(View v)
                      {
                      
                       startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(Resturants.this),SignUpActivity.class));
                      } 
            });

Comment: please just give me an example using a dummy activity class. thanks

Comment: Not sure, perhaps you should try just `getActivity()` without the name class.

Comment: still not working, i know how it is done using the activity class. but the function is different when its a fragment class.

Comment: thanks fllo, it was my mistake. i was passing a param inside the getActivity() lolz. Thanks alot once again